# How to lock files with TFVC REST API?

Tags: c++, rest, tfvc

I'm trying to create a C++ library that uses the TFVC REST API so that I can support TFS from within a program.

I've been successful using rapidjson and chilkat to build and send requests for a lot of the functionality so far-- add, delete, rename, etc.

My issue is that I cannot seem to apply any locks. I want users to be able to 'checkout' a file and to do so a lock must be applied.

This is for a TFS 2017 Server. Here's a link to the TFVC REST API docs 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#versioncontrolchangetype

Here's my test:

```
{
   "changes":[
      {
         "changeType":"lock",
         "item":{
            "contentMetadata":{
               "contentType":"rawText",
               "encoding":1200
            },
            "path":"$/TFStestAT/TextFile1.txt",
           "version":"131"
         }
      }
   ],
   "comment":"(sample) Locking a file via Advanced REST Client"
}
```

Here's the response:

```
{
"$id": "1",
"innerException": null,
"message": "The specified change type Lock is not supported.",
"typeName": "System.ArgumentException, mscorlib",
"typeKey": "ArgumentException",
"errorCode": 0,
"eventId": 0
}
```

With no "checkout" changeType and Lock not being supported, how should I go about locking?
Any tips would be greatly appreciated!